# I wanna remove the mikkymax file

Tags: javascript, wordpress, performance, pagespeed

When I'm optimizing my WordPress website one of the tools indicat that this file make my website slower http://mikkymax.com/20ba4519da0cfb915b.js ,
I did some research I didn't find any source of this file.
How can I remove it or stoped it please?

Comment: I was able to further your research and did find the source. According to this github https://gist.github.com/StudioMaX/62af7d906c7e3ba4df294e4e39026159   the same file is described as *Malware ad-framework used in different browser extensions*. If so, then you could consider just deleting or renaming the file on your server. ... Or in your case, remove or comment out the reference.

Comment: Thank you @GetSet, how can I remove it from my server?

Comment: That I dont know. Im not versed with Wordpress. I would imagine though if you access to your source files (the filesystem), you could perform a search for that reference to see all of which files are infected.

Comment: Thaks a lot ! @GetSet